# rails 3.1 render_to_string returning empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

from a controller method, i'm trying to capture the output of rendering a template from another controller.

the view file is located here:

```
path/to/show.html.erb
```

in my controller i have:

```
def create
  html_string = render_to_string :template => 'path/to/show'
  raise 'html string is empty!' if html_string.empty?
  # do some other stuff
end
```

the view file is very simple, just containing the text 'foo'.

i'm not getting any error about rails not being able to find the show.html.erb file, but 
html_string is empty, and the error is raised.

i'm seeing this behavior when running the create method through an rspec controller test.  i haven't tried the code through the rails server yet.

does anyone see anything i'm missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this turns out to be due to my controller spec missing the important line:

```
render_views
```

Comment: As soon as you are able, be sure and mark this answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
describe UsersController do
 integrate_views
```